# Jquery element+class selector performance

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, performance

I was hoping `$('#childDiv2 .txtClass')` or `$('#childDiv2 input.txtClass')` perform better when selecting `<input type="text" id="txtID" class="txtClass"/>` element. But according to this [performance analysis](http://jsperf.com/selectors-perf/3) `$('.txtClass');` is the best selector among this. I'm using JQuery 1.7.2
Does anybody have explanation for this?

[image: Performance analysis for class selectors]

*HTML*

```
<div class="childDiv2">
    <input type="text" id="txtID" class="txtClass"/>
    <p class="child">Blah Blah Blah</p>
</div>​
```

*JS*

```
$('.txtClass');
$('#childDiv2 .txtClass')
$('#childDiv2 > .txtClass')
$('input.txtClass')
$('#childDiv2 input.txtClass')
```

Comment: As id's have to be unique the fastest way would be `$("#txtID")`

Comment: My concern is select by class scenarios ?

Comment: Great question. I don't have the answer, but it's curious to see that even giving a context $('.txtClass', '#childDiv2') is still slower than the class selector.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Modern browsers expose a very efficient [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) method that returns the elements having a given class. That's why a single class selector is faster in your case.

To elaborate on your examples:

```
$(".txtClass")                  =>  getElementsByClassName()

$("#childDiv2 .txtClass")       =>  getElementById(),
                                    then getElementsByClassName()

$("#childDiv2 > .txtClass")     =>  getElementById(),
                                    then iterate over children and check class

$("input.txtClass")             =>  getElementsByTagName(),
                                    then iterate over results and check class

$("#childDiv2 input.txtClass")  =>  getElementById(),
                                    then getElementsByTagName(),
                                    then iterate over results and check class
```

As you can see, it's quite logical for the first form to be the fastest on modern browsers.

Comment: So what I can tell is almost every jquery performance tutorials found on the web are incorrect. Even tutorials by some jquery guys like [Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/jqprovenperformance/)

Comment: @Lanka, maybe not *incorrect*, just *outdated*. Technology marches on, and the best performance advice today might very well be wrong next year. Benchmarks, on the other hand, will give you up-to-date numbers.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Actually I was wrong in my previous comment. That guy have explained it in the slides.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I think you are wrongly implying with your answer that the way the reading is done is from left-to-right, when in fact in all modern browsers it's from right-to-left with getElementById(), "then" getElementsByTagName() etc. The operations are these, just they don't happen in that order.

Comment: @daremkd, it's not quite RTL (see the comments under [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5813672/464709)). Also, it is done when applying styles, i.e. when the goal is to *find all selectors that match a given element*. `querySelector*()` and especially the Sizzle engine do not share the same goals (theirs is to *find all the elements that match a given selector*) and I doubt they would choose RTL at the cost of performance (especially Sizzle).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Oh, so as far as I understand, say you have "input.a a#b", "input.a" and "a#b" are compound selectors, so in this case, "a#b" will be selected first (but not evaluated necessarily in RTL order), right?

Answer (score 8):

```
var obj = document.getElementById("childDiv");
xxx = obj.getElementsByClassName("txtClass");
```

is 30x faster.

http://jsperf.com/selectors-perf/6

Answer (score 6):

CSS Selectors are parsed from right to left. So your example

```
$('#childDiv2 .txtClass')
```

will take two actions to complete. First find all elements with class `txtClass`. Then check each element for being a child of the element with the id `childDiv2`.

```
$('.txtClass')
```

This selector will just take one action. Find all elements with class `txtClass`

Have a look at [this article](http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/) on css-tricks.com

Comment: As I know sizzle optimize this query. So it's work differently than your explanation. It's first select the childDiv2 and then search for txtClass in it's children.

Comment: actually, the first code line shown requires checking each .txtClass element to see if it is a DESCENDANT of #childDiv2. That requires examining ALL the ancestors of each .txtClass.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it also depends on the density of the elements with the class among the elements of the type.

I ran the tests with Google Chrome Version 30.0.1599.69 using JQuery 1.10.1. Feel free to try it on another browser and/or using another JQuery version.

I tried to run the following tests:

1. Sparse (10% of the div's have the class) [link to the test on
   jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EhOSIte/3/edit)
2. Dense (90% of the div's have the class) [link to the test on
   jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EhOSIte/2/edit)

Looks like in the **Dense case** `div.class` wins, but in the **Sparse case** `.class` wins.

Comment: Like comments which mention dense/sparse, this is often overlooked. There is no silver bullet apart from using an id if you can.