# jQuery how to properly use onChange

Tags: jquery, drupal, onchange

I am using Drupal  7 (quite new to both Drupal and Javascript / jQuery) and I got a class called "field-name-field-activity", now what I want is to put an onchange of every input in that class.

```
jQuery('.field-name-field-activity :input').onchange = function() {
    //enter code here
};
```

I am not sure if I'm using my onchange right here, I also saw some people using onChange instead of onchange, not sure what the difference is, but can anybody tell me how to use onchange the right way in my example?

Comment: What is the type of the html element you are applying this event on?

Comment: It is an input of type text.

Comment: Do you want to bind an event handler to elements with `class="field-name-field-activity"` or to `<input>` descendants of an element with that class name? Your selector is currently doing the latter.

Comment: Its `jQuery('input.field-name-field-activity').change()`
which will select all the input elements with class field-name-field-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple error of syntax try this `jQuery('.field-name-field-activity :input').change(function() {
    //enter code here
});`

here is a link to the api reference http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I can only give one accepted answer, I'll give it to the person who answered first. (I'm sorry everyone else!) :(

Answer (score 4):

With jquery just `change` will work:

```
$('.field-name-field-activity').change(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

**Edit:**

As the event is to be bind with text type, a better way is to use `input` event like:

```
$('.field-name-field-activity').on('input', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

The `onchange` event may not work correctly on some browsers in case of text fields.

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document" - see [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) documentation.

Comment: Oh yes, my sincere apologies! I completely misread the revision history.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
jQuery('.field-name-field-activity input').change(function() {
    //enter code here
});
```

[**SIMPLE DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2pzrg/)

Comment: Where exactly do you end the change event here?

Comment: You have never ended your change(, but I suppose it ends after the curly bracket }

Comment: Hes getting at a typo your missing the ending )

Comment: @user1841216: yes, you are right. It ends after the curly bracket `}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
jQuery('.field-name-field-activity').on('change',function() {
    //enter code here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Your selector is different to the one in the question

Comment: If you are not sure, then you should clarify with the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning performance I would suggest not to use the ":input"-Selector.

> Because :input is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using >:input cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM >querySelectorAll() method.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

If the classname relates to input-Elements only anyway, just use the class-selector like Ankit Jaiswal suggested, because a single-class-selector performs best.

Source: [Jquery element+class selector performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698935/jquery-elementclass-selector-performance)