# Better JQuery performance syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any performance difference implication for the 2 syntax below?

1. `$(“span.foo”)`
2. `$(“.foo”)`

Someone told me the first one would merely search `span` whose class is `foo` while the second would search among all elements.

Comment: Someone copy/pasted code from Word, `” != "`

Comment: Well, of course they select different things. That's how CSS selectors work. The performance difference is irrelevant. Use the one that selects the elements you need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698935/jquery-elementclass-selector-performance

Comment: It's semi-irrelevant, unless it is perceived by the user. Hopefully you'll never have [25,333](http://jsfiddle.net/Af4mM/) lines of varied class and element markup to go through.

Comment: They're doing different things. Trying to compare them for performance isn't meaningful. Apples to oranges, etc.

Comment: @ChristopherW: I meant that since the selectors have different meaning, the performance difference doesn't matter so much as using the proper selector to fetch the correct elements. That said, if performance is really a concern, the first thing to do is to eliminate abstractions.

Comment: @squint, it was a comment to the OP. Sorry for the mix up.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a performance related issue, it is always better to benchmark the different solutions to see which one is better.

They both may have different results bases on the markup.

But if you have only `span`'s with the class `foo` then the second one will be faster.
<sub>The reason could be in the first case it will first load all span's in the document then filter them with the class `foo` while the second one will you the native `getElementsByClassname` to fetch the elements.</sub>

Have a look at this [jsperf benchmark](http://jsperf.com/jquery-select-with-element-and-class)

Answer (score 1):

Who ever told you that is correct.

Looks like it is about a half a second(Firefox, Chrome is less than that) when selecting on two elements over 100,000 iterations.

http://jsfiddle.net/83qcy/

```
var start, end, i;

start = new Date();
for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
    $("span.foo");
}
end = new Date();
$("span.foo").html(end - start);

start = new Date();
for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
    $(".foo");
}
end = new Date();
$("div.foo").html(end - start);
```

I'm sure you can imaging that selecting on a larger amount of elements would certainly take longer. You likely won't select 100,000 times either, but as websites get larger javascript performance can be one of the largest factors, jQuery's context and selectors can make that much more efficient.

Also, you may be selecting elements that you don't want if you only want to apply functions to spans with a class of "foo"