# How to measure the performance advantage arising due to Jquery event delegation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

My webpage has a grid which contains 500 rows and 30 columns. Each cell is either a dropdown or a textbox. As of now, we are attaching 'change' events to each of these elements individually.

Recently, I learnt that JQuery event delegation using 'on' method can improve performance.  t

I created two prototypes one with event delegation and one without it.

Without event delegation:

http://jsfiddle.net/djaoru53/

```
$(".event").click(function(){
    alert("click");
});
```

With event delegation:

http://jsfiddle.net/15cswkq7/

```
$("#test").on("click",".event", function(){
    alert("click");
});
```

How should I measure the performance improvement that I get on my webpage by using event delegation?

What tools can I use and what should I measure?

Answer (score 1):

[Jslitmus](http://broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/) a good tool to measure performance

Well actually You can do same in a firebug also 
read full conversation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7118682/2630817)

[Speed tracer is also a good tool](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/).

[Here's](http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/) one good article also